# Check if payment received paypal?

Tags: html, css, paypal, web, widget

I am making a website where people will buy things.  What I am wondering is if there is a way to check if payment was received in paypal, and then execute some code.  Or should I add a paypal widget where when payment is done then it executes some code?  This is all being done in HTML and CSS being it is a website.

Comment: If it's "all being done in HTML and CSS being it is a website," what code will you be executing? Also, this is a duplicate question, look here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780964/receive-form-only-if-paypal-payment-is-complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).  Any time a transaction hits your PayPal account their server will POST the transaction data to a URL you specify.  Your script receives the data, verifies it with PayPal to ensure it actually came from them, and then you can process that data however you need to.

This gives you the ability to update your own database, send out your own email notifications, hit 3rd party web services, or anything else you want to automate when transactions hit your account.  This works for payments, refunds, disputes, etc. so you can automate lots of tasks.  It happens in real-time, too.